# jQuery: find all the different content value for a given tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like:

```
function(xml){
$(xml).find('tag').each(function(){
//do something});
}
```

How can I make it cycle only over the tag elements that have different .text() values?

eg.: I have

```
    <'tag>Hello<'/tag>
    <'tag>Hello<'/tag>
    <'tag>Bye<'/tag>
    <'tag>Hello<'/tag>
```

and I want to obtain only: Hello, Bye

Lorenzo

Comment: So you need to do something with just the first tag with content Hello?

Comment: I need to get each different text() inside the 'tag' tag.

Comment: Great so I think that I've posted the right solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS**

```
var history = {},
    value;
$('div').each(function () {
    value = $(this).text();
    if (history[value] === undefined) {
        alert(value);
        history[value] = true;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Bye</div>
<div>Foo</div>
<div>Bar</div>
<div>Foo</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uuw5r/1/

Comment: works like a charm. It's a pity that jQuery doesn't have this as a built-in function!

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery [.contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

$("tag:contains('Hello'), tag:contains('Bye')")

Comment: but what if I have an undefined number of text() values? I know that in xQuery you can call something like: for each different tag..do something.